# C# Webclient Download String Zero Result in Json File

Tags: c#, json, webclient

I have a Problem with the webClient.Download("URI") function. It worked, since I had to change the URL to https (what I suggest). If I paste my request URI in the Browser i get a valid Json String, if I call it with the DownloadString("URI") method, i get Zero Results as a result
My Code contains a key, just removed it for this post here
here is my Code:

```
var json = "";

Console.WriteLine("Connect zur Google API Geo Coding API");
locations = locations.Replace(" ", "+");
//request the google geocoding api. limit of 2500 requests/day
String requestUri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Serba,++Am+Schwemmberg,+Germany";
Console.WriteLine("Hat geklappt");
//get the json string
 Console.WriteLine("starte den download des json");

 var webClient = new WebClient();
//here it Returns "Zero result"

 json = webClient.DownloadString(requestUri);

 Console.WriteLine("Download des json beendet");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) states that you have to provide the `key` parameter which you didn't.

Comment: I added a key in my Code, just dont have it here in, sorry